# jQuery: how to access parent function "this" from inside anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
...
$.fn.annotateEdit = function(image, note) {
    if (note) {
        this.note = note;
    } else {
        var newNote = new Object();
        newNote.id = "new";
        this.note = newNote;
    }
}
...
var mynote = this.note;

form.find(':radio').change(function() {
    var vacancy = $(this).attr('value');
    mynote.vacancy = vacancy;
});
...
```

Is it possible to access "this.note" from the change() handler without defining "mynote"?

Comment: Thanks for all the uber fast accurate replies. I can only pick one as answer, so I'll go with the simplest - the "that" pattern. But the others are definitely not any less valuable.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I use a pattern like this so I can access anything in the enclosing scope:

```
var that = this;
...

form.find(':radio').change(function () {
    that.note.vacancy = $(this).attr('value');
});
```

I am a fan of this pattern because it makes the code a little more readable. In my opinion, it is clear what it being accessed is part of the enclosing scope (as long as the usage of `that` is consistent).

Comment: Have seen this pattern a few times before, but its similar to his `mynote` definition, no?

Comment: Similar but not quite, `var mynote = this.note` limits him to just using the `note` variable, but my method lets him access anything in the scope. It makes the code a little more readable because it is clear what it being accessed (as long as you are consistent with the usage of `that`).

Comment: True, yea I guess thats why I see this a lot of places in JS code :)

Answer (score 5):

Use `$.proxy` to bind it to a function...

```
   // Returns a function-------v
form.find(':radio').change( $.proxy(function() {

    var vacancy = $(this).attr('value');
    mynote.vacancy = vacancy;

}, this) );
//   ^---- ...that has its "this" value set as this argument.
```

Comment: I see using $.proxy as a more elegant solution, but would like to understand: is this better solution from the one that has been accepted as an answer or not? whats the difference?

Answer (score 3):

There is no dedicated language mechanism for it. The common pattern is to store the `this` in local (closure) variable (often named `self` or `that`) of the outer function:

```
var self = this;
var innerFunction = function() {
    self.x = 1;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this - http://api.jquery.com/bind/ and "Passing event data"
You can do something like this :

```
form.find(':radio').bind("change", {
context : this
}, function(event){
    console.log(event.data.context);
    console.log(event.data.context.note);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the context of the parent object like so.

```
form.find(':radio').change(function(that) {
    var vacancy = $(this).attr('value');
    that.note.vacancy = vacancy;
}.bind(null,this));
```